# Dictionary: hard-coded vs. external file

Tags: java, performance, dictionary, coding-style, hardcode

I have a java application which is started and stopped multiple times per second over hundreds of millions of items (called from an external script).

```
Input: String key
Output: int value
```

The purpose of this application is to look for a certain key in a never *ever ever* changing `Map` (~30k keys) and to return the value. Very easy.

> **Question: what is more efficient when used multiple times per second:**
>
> 1. hard-coded dictionary in a `Map`
> 2. Read an external file with a `BufferedReader`
> 3. *...amaze me with your other ideas*

I know hard-coding is *evil* but sometimes, you need to be evil to be efficient :-)

Comment: It would be better to have the map on the fly for easy access regarding your Java app.

Comment: Using a database is an option ?

Comment: Why are you starting and stopping the app so much? Why not just leave it running and process requests as needed?

Comment: The problem here is the fact that you relaunch your Java App hundreds of millions of times. The startup overhead is likely to be 99% of the processing time.  You need to rethink things so your app can service requests over a pipe or socket and startup only once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read in the dictionary from file. Store it in a `Map`. Set up your Java application as a service that runs continuously (since you said it gets called many times per second). Then your `Map` will be cached in RAM.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest is a hard coded map in memory.
if u a have a huge file you can use a Memory Mapped file :

```
MappedByteBuffer in = new FileInputStream("map.txt").getChannel().map(
FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, LENGTH);
StringBuilder bs = new StringBuilder();
//read 1/4 of the file   
while (i < LENGTH/4)
      bs.append((char)in.get(i++));
```

This approach is a bit problematic though,in practice you will want to partition the file
on line breaks i.e read until the 100th line clean the buffer and read some more.

Answer (score 0):

I would load the file into a `Map` at startup of the application, and then use it as you describe.

I would store the data in a database for faster load times.

Definitely do not have the application startup and shutdown every time it is called; have it as a service that waits for IO, using Asynchronous I/O, such as [netty](http://netty.io)